# Can't launch mist wallet. Stuck after pressing 'launch application' in windows 10

Tags: mist, synchronization, windows

[image]

Hi. 
I downloaded Mist wallet and then after some time when the 'launch application' button came up, I pressed that. However, now I only see the following image on my screen and the figures shown below are stuck in that state for more than an hour. Do I need to do something differently?

Comment: I'm using Mist Windows 64 bits, v 0.9.0 (from https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases ) and am on Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Solved: The only problem here was the lack of the update display. It continued to download data and then restarted it after some hours and was able to access the wallet.